# if G is abelian group and it has cyclic subgroup of order 5 and 4 then what are d other sizes of cyclic group that G must have?

Tags: group-theory

As G hs cyclic subgroup of order 4 then as 2 divides 4 so it must have cyclic subgroup of order 2. BUt in text it is given that G olso have cyclic subgroup of order 20. 
How please explain?

Comment: Do you know how the order of the product of elements is computed, given the order of each?

Comment: No sir please tell

Comment: Then try computing it. Compute (ab)^2, (ab)^3, and so on until you see a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $a$ and $b$ are generators of cyclic subgroups of order $4$ and $5$ respectively then $ab$ is of order $20.$

Comment: But in case when order are not coprime like if we take subgroup of order 4 and other of 6 then what will we do?

Comment: @SajanPhutela in that case there is not much that can be said in general. For example, you can have $a$ and $b=a^{-1}$ in which case the order of $ab$ will be $1$. The problem you are given is specifically designed to exploit relative primality.

Comment: @AnuragA If $a$ and $b$ have orders $m$ and $n$ respectively then the order of $ab$ need not be $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$, but the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ must have an element of order $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

For general case - 
If $G$ is an abelian group and contains cyclic subgroups of order n and m ,it will contain a cyclic subgroup of order $lcm(n,m)$

If $G$,an abelian group has cyclic subgroups of order 4 and 5 ,it will contain a cyclic subgroup of order 20 .
And by fundamental theorem of cyclic groups ,it will contain subgroups of orders 1,2,4,5,10,20.

Note - For abelian group ,converse of Lagrange's theorem is true.